# Subdomain created using DirectAdmin not resolving

Tags: dns, subdomain

I am trying to create a subdomain using DirectAdmin. The subdomain will be finance.nickputman.com

I appear to have successfully created the subdomain in that there are A records for finance and www.finance showing under 'DNS management', and when I carry out an online DNS propagation check for the A records, all reports come back as successful.

And yet when I try to visit http://finance.nickputman.com I get a server not found error.  http://nickputman.com/finance works OK.

Is there another step I need to take to get this working?

Comment: works fine here - did you clear your local dns cache?

Comment: @Gryphius Ah, thanks. That did the trick. If you want to add an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some time before new/changed dns records are fetched by your local dns cache (depending on the TTL values of the old records). Manually clear the dns cache to force an update.